# What is the exact grammar for Angulars structural directives

Tags: angular, angular-template

Angulars [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax) explains, that structural directives, such as `<p *ngIf="a as b"></p>` are "desugared" into `<p [ngIf]="a" [ngIfAs]="b">`.

The desugaring makes use of the `microsyntax`, that allows for expressions like

```
let node; when: hasChild
a as b
let x of y; index = i; trackBy: f
```

The documentation provides some examples of the microsyntax, and suggest studying the sources of `ngIf`, but it provides no formal definition.

**What is the grammar for the microsyntax of angular's structural directives?**

Answer (score 9):

There is [special section for grammar of structual directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directive-syntax-reference) in Angular docs.

You can check out my [**interactive DEMO**](https://alexzuza.github.io/ng-structural-directive-expander/)

[image]

So, what's the logic here?

Once Angular meets structural directive it tries to parse it:

```
 *dir="..."
/\
indicates that it's a structural directive
```

At the beginning there are 3 cases:

```
*dir="expr
       \/
   [dir]="expr"

*dir="let var  // also var can have value
       \/ // starts with keyword 'let', indicates variable
   [dir] let-x="$impicit"


*dir="as var
      \/ // starts with keyword 'as'
  let-x="$implicit" // it won't fail but your directive won't be instantiated
```

After an expression you can use either  `as` keyword to define template input variable for that expression or a separator such as whitespace, colon, semicolon or comma:

```
*dir="expr as var
 \/
[dir]="exp" let-var="dir"

*dir="expr[ ]
*dir="expr:
*dir="expr;
*dir="expr,
```

Note that `dir` is considered here as the first template binding key.

Now it's time to another key or variable:

```
*dir="expr key2
*dir="expr:key2
*dir="expr;key2
*dir="expr,key2
```

And we can assign value to that key through whitespace or semicolon:

```
*dir="expr key2 exp2
*dir="expr:key2 exp2
*dir="expr;key2 exp2
*dir="expr,key2 exp2
or
*dir="expr key2:exp2
```

And this way we can produce other keys. These key are capitalized and concatenated with the first key.

```
*dir="expr key2 exp2 key3 exp3 ...
\/
[dir]="expr " [dirKey2]="exp2 " [dirKey3]="exp3"


let node; when: hasChild; otherKey: otherValue
  \/       \/      \/
  var     key    value
                         \/
dir [dirWhen]="hasChild" [dirOtherKey]="otherValue" let-node="$implicit"


*dir="let x of y; index = i; trackBy: f"
           \/
dir [dirOf]="y" [dirIndex]="= i" [dirTrackBy]="f" let-x="$implicit"

*dir="let x  of   y;  let index = i; trackBy: f"
        \/   \/   \/      \/           \/    \/
        var  key  value     var          key   value
                   \/
dir [dirOf]="y" [dirTrackBy]="f" let-x="$implicit" let-index="i"
```

As you can see we can either define key-value or set [template input variables](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#template-input-variable) through `let` or as `keywords`

If you think that Angular docs doesn't completely explain it then you can follow [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d8665e639b45952953d4db02e7392865e8fa7a38/packages/compiler/src/expression_parser/parser.ts#L681-L735)

```typescript
  // Parses the AST for `<some-tag *tplKey=AST>`
  parseTemplateBindings(tplKey: string): TemplateBindingParseResult {
    let firstBinding = true;
    const bindings: TemplateBinding[] = [];
    const warnings: string[] = [];
    do {
      const start = this.inputIndex;
      let rawKey: string;
      let key: string;
      let isVar: boolean = false;
      if (firstBinding) {
        rawKey = key = tplKey;
        firstBinding = false;
      } else {
        isVar = this.peekKeywordLet();
        if (isVar) this.advance();
        rawKey = this.expectTemplateBindingKey();
        key = isVar ? rawKey : tplKey + rawKey[0].toUpperCase() + rawKey.substring(1);
        this.optionalCharacter(chars.$COLON);
      }

      let name: string = null !;
      let expression: ASTWithSource|null = null;
      if (isVar) {
        if (this.optionalOperator('=')) {
          name = this.expectTemplateBindingKey();
        } else {
          name = '\$implicit';
        }
      } else if (this.peekKeywordAs()) {
        this.advance();  // consume `as`
        name = rawKey;
        key = this.expectTemplateBindingKey();  // read local var name
        isVar = true;
      } else if (this.next !== EOF && !this.peekKeywordLet()) {
        const start = this.inputIndex;
        const ast = this.parsePipe();
        const source = this.input.substring(start - this.offset, this.inputIndex - this.offset);
        expression = new ASTWithSource(ast, source, this.location, this.errors);
      }

      bindings.push(new TemplateBinding(this.span(start), key, isVar, name, expression));
      if (this.peekKeywordAs() && !isVar) {
        const letStart = this.inputIndex;
        this.advance();                                   // consume `as`
        const letName = this.expectTemplateBindingKey();  // read local var name
        bindings.push(new TemplateBinding(this.span(letStart), letName, true, key, null !));
      }
      if (!this.optionalCharacter(chars.$SEMICOLON)) {
        this.optionalCharacter(chars.$COMMA);
      }
    } while (this.index < this.tokens.length);

    return new TemplateBindingParseResult(bindings, warnings, this.errors);
}
```

The code above describes the algorithm of how a structural directive is parsed.

See also

- https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directive-syntax-reference

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the following code:

```
<div *ngIf="hero" class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
```

turns into:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="hero">
  <div class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Angular creates this ng-template tag around your div and evaluates the if before deciding whether to add the div or not. The ng-template is a phantom tag that does not exist in the DOM(does not disturb the css) and does some logic.

Comment: i understand that template tags will be added. What im interested in is the specification of HOW the translation of the microsyntax into these templates happens. Consider `let node; when: hasChild` `a as b` and `let x of y; index = i; trackBy: f`: there is much more to it.