# custom if directive does not show expected results

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

in this tutorial

```
https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angular-directives/
```

i am learning how to create a customised directive. i followed the steps as shown in the code posted below, but despite added the exact code as explained in the aforemenrtioned website, when i run the command

```
ng serve --open
```

i get something as shown in the image posted below.
please let me know why myCustomIf is not working. i say that myCustomIf is not working because what i got on the localhost:4200 is something as shown in the image posted

please let me know how to make the myCustomIf works as explained in the tutorial in the above posted link

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ngDirective1';
  name = 'Angular';
  condition = false;    

}
```

**app.myCustomeIfDirective.ts**:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myCustomIf]'
})
export class MyCustomeIfDirective{
    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef){ }

    @Input()
    setMyCustomIf(condition : boolean) {
        if(condition) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

**app.module**:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myCustomIf]'
})
export class MyCustomeIfDirective{
    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef){ }

    @Input()
    setMyCustomIf(condition : boolean) {
        if(condition) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<h1 my-error>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<h2 *myCustomIf="condition">Hello {{name}}</h2>
<button (click)="condition = !condition">Click</button>
```

**image**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open console it should show smth like:

> NG0303: Can't bind to 'myCustomIf' since it isn't a known property of
> 'h2'

An Angular structural directive, that is written in a short syntax(with `*`) and that takes one input or more inputs, must have an `@Input` with the same name as directive's attribute selector(other inputs follow another rule described here [What is the exact grammar for Angulars structural directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062311/what-is-the-exact-grammar-for-angulars-structural-directives/56064653#56064653)), e.g.:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[anyAttr]'
})
export class MyCustomeIfDirective{
    @Input()
    anyAttr: any;
```

or

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[anotherAttr]'
})
export class MyCustomeIfDirective{
    @Input()
    set anotherAttr(val: any) {}
```

Why is it so?

That's because `*ngIf` is just a shortcut for expanded version:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="...">...
```

or

```
*anyAttr => <ng-template [anyAttr]="...">...
```

Now, let's look at your code:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myCustomIf]'
})
export class MyCustomeIfDirective{
    @Input()
    setMyCustomIf(condition : boolean) {
```

Several things to notice:

- `setMyCustomIf` is just a method in your case
- if you convert it to a setter `set MyCustomIf` then `MyCustomIf` doesnt match `myCustomIf` because js is case-sensitive.

The solution is:

```
@Input()
set myCustomIf(condition : boolean) {
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/CPIp0wNgcbETIymqYveL)**

Comment: "An Angular structural directive must have an @Input with the same name as directive's attribute selector" isn't really true in general terms.

Comment: I read your answer but it is still vague where the error is!!the code still does not work

Comment: @IngoBürk Can you give me an example where it is not true? Input alias and directive without input are exceptions

Comment: @user2121 The error is in angular binding `*myCustomIf="condition"` I added an example of my change

Comment: @yurzui For example I've had a project where different user roles existed (viewer, admin, ...) and there were structural directives `*appViewer` and `*appAdmin` to only show things for those roles. Those structural directives didn't have any inputs whatsoever. And even if they do have an input, choosing the same name as the selector is only to make for a shorter syntax — it's not a requirement for a structural directives to work at all.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thank you. I got what you mean. I corrected my answer a little.

Comment: Would you pls tell me what is the purpose of set keyword that precedes the name of the method

Comment: @user2121 This is js syntax for setter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set It allows us to intercept any property change and do our stuff depending on updated value

Answer (score 0):

in your directive (**app.myCustomeIfDirective.ts**), you need to match the name of your input to the name of the directive (because the condition is passed with that attribute):

```
@Input("myCustomIf")
set myCustomIf(condition : boolean) {
    if(condition) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
}
```

(note you can also change the name of the function to match the directive name)

stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-custom-ng-if?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-custom-if.directive.ts)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem

Comment: @user2121 -  see my edit - changed from function to setter

Comment: AFAIK, input alias is not needed here if you use the same input name

Comment: you are correct, the alias isn't needed (but wont interfere)

Comment: I changed the name of the method to match the name of directive selector. But still no change occurred..the problem still exist

Comment: @user2121 yo are doing something wrong... see this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-custom-ng-if?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-custom-if.directive.ts